# SmsManager cant receive any messages when it generate

Tags: java, android, smsmanager

My SMS app was working from android studio , when it generates from the phone, cant receive any message, my sample contact number "+639123456789" (phone # for Philippines). from the android studio, im using number is 5554 and it works , can receive a message.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText num = findViewById(R.id.e1);
    final EditText mes = findViewById(R.id.e2);
    Button btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
            String S1 = num.getText().toString();
            String S2 = mes.getText().toString();
            sendSMS(S1,S2);}
            catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e+" & ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Error: ", String.valueOf(e));
            }
       /*here i can send message to emulator 5556. In Real device
        *you can change number*/
        }
    });
}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);

}}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

> 04-27 15:40:36.728 6258-6258/com.example.coorsdev.textmessage E/Error:: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid destinationAddress

Comment: `Invalid destinationAddress` Are you using a valid number ? Also just make sure you asked for RuntimePermission.

Comment: That particular Exception is only thrown if the phone number is empty. Are you sure you're getting the number from the right `EditText`, and that it's not empty when you send?

Comment: can u please help me out im stuck , in other words, i want create program sending sms like MightyText app with customize

Comment: My comment above explains the reason for that particular Exception. You'll need to figure out how you're ending up with an empty phone number. We can't tell that from the given code.

Comment: number/empty number , still same error.

Comment: How exactly are you determining that `phoneNumber` is not empty when you call `sendTextMessage()`?

Comment: I saw the problem. i forgot when sending with number , but cant receive the error. what is goin on? thanks for find error . youre correct but error cant show when send right?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: if send without number , i receive the error.
if send with number , nothing happen, no error receive from logcat

Comment: Do you mean that the message is not delivered, but you're not getting an error?

Comment: yes, not getting error,

Comment: The `sendTextMessage()` method will fail silently if the text is longer than the maximum character limit for a single-part message. How long is your message? Have you tried it with a really short message?